# What's the maximum filename length in encrypted ext4 partition?

Tags: 11.10, encryption, ext4, encrypted-partition, filename

I'm using a two-partition setup with ubuntu (one partition for the system, one for my home directories). Until now I had an ext3 formatted home partition, which I'm currently trying to migrate to an encrypted ext4 partition.

However, when copying the files the system is bugging me with errors, complaining that filenames are too long. As far as I could find out using wikipedia filename length is 255 bytes for ext3 and 256 bytes for ext4. So where's the problem, and how can I solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/344878) about encryptfs for along time. As you can see this is a huge bug and whishlist. They are struggling with to support this [for 12.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/344878/comments/79). I couldn't see a neat solution but [there is a workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/344878/comments/56). But those files are missing right now. A PPA is [being set up](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/344878/comments/59) but there are'nt any package right now.

So, I can't see a direct solution for this problem. Maybe you can ask John Johansen for a new kernel which is for Oneric.

Note: I couldn't read all the comments, there is a possibility that I missed something. ie, there could be a solution or this possible solution (Johansen's) could harm your files.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info! I guess I just have to live with shorter file names at the moment, the workaround seems not to be a stable solution for now.

Comment: You are welcome, I hope this will be fix in 12.04.

Comment: It should be, as its status in Precise is **In Progress** and `precise-alpha-2` is set as a milestone (from the bug page).

Comment: Yeah @Eliah Kagan, there is a milestone for 12.04, but I see there was a milestone(s) for Natty also :)